# Implementing an iterator for a stack

Tags: java, iterator, arraylist, stack

I defined an interface **StringStack**

```
public interface StringStack{
    //add a value to the stack
    public void push(String value);
    //fetch top-most element of the stack. element is removed
    public String pop();
    //fetch top-most element of the stack. element is not removed
    public String peek();
}
```

Further I defined a class **SimpleStack** that uses an **ArrayList** to manage the stack

```
public class SimpleStack implements StringStack{
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void push(String value){
        list.add(value);
    }

    public String pop(){
        if(!list.isEmpty()){
                return list.remove(list.size() - 1);
        }else{
                return null;
        }
    }

   public String peek(){
        if(!list.isEmpty()){
                return list.get(list.size() - 1);
        }else{
                return null;
        }
}
```

Now I want define an iterator for my stack class but I don't want to use the built-in ArrayList iterator. So I came up implementing a inner class and extending my SimpleStack with the **Iterable** interface.

So I have now:

```
 public class SimpleStack implements StringStack, Iterable<String>

 ...

 public Iterator<String> iterator(){
    return new StackEnum();
 }

 class StackEnum implements Iterator<String>{

    int pos = list.size();

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return pos != 0;
    }

    public String next(){
        if(pos != 0){
            String str = list.get(pos);
            pos--;
        }else{
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
 }
```

I am absolutely not sure how to perform the iteration inside the iterator. Since my stack is represented by an array list I used list.size() as top-element.

Am I right with my implementation of the iterator, especially the next method?

Comment: Implementation looks OK to me. Just one question: why don't you use [`java.util.Stack<E>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)? Is it because its `iterator()` returns element not in stack order?

Comment: Like the answers you right too. But I pointed out that I don't want to use built-in features, I just practice to get familar with some basic oop features

Comment: So, finally I don't understand why you selected [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632600/implementing-an-iterator-for-a-stack/5632695#5632695) as answer? Here you simply accept to use the built in java `Stack`!

Comment: Give an answer and I will yours ;)

Comment: I mean [das_weezul's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632600/implementing-an-iterator-for-a-stack/5632710#5632710) is much more in the direction that you were looking for: suggestion for implementing your own stack iterator!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if an Iterator for a stack is a good idea, as the typical behavior of a stack does not conform to the iterator-protocol, as you'd have to pop an element to reveal the next one. I would suggest to add a public method like `getList()` which returns a list-representation of the stack. The list then could implement the Iterator interface. You could just return a copy of the ArrayList like that:

```
public List<String> returnList() {
  return new ArrayList<String>(list); // Return a copy of the ArrayList
}
```